# users other than root cannot access Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I am facing a weird problem with my Hadoop setup for a single node machine where users other than root cannot execute hadoop.

Basically, I followed Cloudera instruction to install CDH5 on Ubuntu using a single node mode. As a result, hadoop can be called successfully from the root account using sudo:

```
$ sudo hadoop fs -ls /
Found 3 items
drwxrwxrwt   - hdfs supergroup          0 2014-12-03 00:45 /tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs supergroup          0 2014-12-03 00:48 /user
drwxr-xr-x   - hdfs supergroup          0 2014-12-03 00:46 /var
```

However, using normal user account, it throws an error:

```
$ hadoop fs -ls /
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell
```

I thought the problem might be because of some access issues to the library files but was not able to find which library file in order to fix it. Any suggestion to solve this issue is appreciated.

Comment: make sure the `CLASSPATH` settings are same and assign the user to the same group of root user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was because of different environmental settings for the "root" and "my-user" accounts. during the process, I setup the $HADOOP_HOME in my .bashrc which was forcing "my-user" account to use an obsolete path. Adjusting that based on root account setting solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup a new user directory with the user you need to give permission.

Follow [step 11](http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/05/hadoop-installation-using-cloudera.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks I tried that but had the same error as before: "Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell"